# Center dynamic div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a header `width:100%`, inside it I have a dynamic div. The div can have any width size, so, by default, it's inheriting `width:100%` from header. In this case `margin:0 auto` won't work, and if I `float:left` this div, I can't use `margin:0 auto` either.

What's the best solution to center this div?

Comment: If the child has the same width as the parent ( here 100% ) the child is already centred. Think about it!!!

Comment: Please post your code and explain the results you are experiencing vs. the results you expect.

Comment: by your description `margin:auto` should have worked. something is wrong. show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `text-align: center` on the outer `<div>` and `display: inline-block` and `text-align: left` on the inner block.

For all centering questions take a look at [CSS-Tricks guide](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

```css
.outer {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #f99;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #f99;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Inner content<br>
    Another line of content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `display:table;margin:0 auto;` in the dynamic div and it worked.